# Sprite::create(“file.png”) return null on Cocos2d-x C++ Visual Studio

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to create a Sprite with SonarFrameworks, and get a null although my file is well integrated into the project.[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to add :

```
FileUtils::getInstance()->addSearchPath("res/");
```

And try with Content property set to "True" and "False" (default), but still same problem.
[image]

Any idea ?

Comment: It looks like the `background` is set to "res/mainMenue.png", but the file is in "resource/mainMenu.png" - try changing it to that.

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work :/

Comment: hmm... My guess is that the problem is the program can't find the file.

what if you try adding the search path with the same folder like this?: `FileUtils::getInstance()->addSearchPath("resource/");`

If that doesn't work, can you try printing out the searchPaths right before creating the sprite? with this `cout << FileUtils::getInstance()->getSearchPaths (); ` If the search paths are way off, that could explain it :)

Comment: I tried with /resource but same result.
With getSearchPaths I got : "H:/Programs/TicTacToe/TicTacToe/proj.win32/Debug.win32/Resources/" by defaut
So I tried with /Resources but same result...

I saw this message : "cocos2d: fullPathForFilename: No file found at Resource/mainMenu.png. Possible missing file."

Comment: Just for kicks, what happens if you rename the "resource" folder, to "Resource" (with a capital 'R'). Will the program find it then?

Comment: I tried but it makes same result, I tried to rename "res" on my computer to "resource" or Resources but this prevents the program from starting for various reasons.

But I understood what is the problem, addSearchPath is only adding path AFTER "/Resources", so I need to replace this constante, but I can't it with "ctrl+shift+f"

I'm actually searching how to do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225083/discussion-between-l-charly-and-gandhigandhi).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to GandhiGandhi I found the solution :

In the function **FileUtils::fullPathForFilename** located in the file **CCFileUtils.cpp**, a added this

```
    std::string search = searchIt;
    int tail = search.size() - 10; // For replace /Resources
    search.replace(tail, 9, "res");
```

After the first "for(...){", so like that I replaced the path to find my resources.

```
for (const std::string& searchIt : _searchPathArray)
{
    std::string search = searchIt;
    int tail = search.size() - 10; // For replace /Resources
    search.replace(tail, 9, "res");

    for (const auto& resolutionIt : _searchResolutionsOrderArray)
    {
        fullpath = this->getPathForFilename(newFilename, resolutionIt, search);

        if (!fullpath.empty())
        {
            // Using the filename passed in as key.
            _fullPathCache.emplace(filename, fullpath);
            return fullpath;
        }

    }
}
```